# Syntax for creating a Variable of Sub Class

Tags: c++, oop

```
template <class T>
class Stack
{
private:
    template <class L>
    class List
    {
    public:
        class Node
        {
        public:
            L data;
            Node* next;
        };
    Node* head;
};
    List<T> list;
public:
};
```

I want to create a variable of class Node in Stack class and I'm using this syntax

> ```
>  List<T>::Node version;
> ```

But Visual Studio gives it at as syntax error. Please help me

Comment: Try `typename List<T>::Node version;`.

Comment: Thanks it worked But what it's use here ? #songyuanyao

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: Because `List<T>::Node` is dependent on template parameter `T`, the standards says we have to use `typename` to tell the compiler `List<T>::Node` is a name of type (not other things like name of member). See the link posted by @NickyC for details.

Answer (score 0):

As  @songyuanyao said Try 
`typename List<T>::Node version;` 
to create a variable of class Node in Stack class